# How to download gapps

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I flashed cyanogen mod 12 on my galaxy s3. Once I did that I flashed gapps but when I went to turn my phone on, every single app crashed and kept crashing literally over and over again. I couldn't do anything but press OK when they crashed because when I tried to, another one just popped up. Is there any way that I can just apk the Google play store or something.

Comment: "Just apk-ing the Play Store" is impossible, since there are other files (besides .apk files) that make the Play Store work.

Answer (score 2):

The error occoured because the gapps version you installed didnot match the version of os installed. You can find the minimal gapps edition [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/gapps-google-apps-minimal-edition-t2943330).Since you are running cm12 you should download download the one meant for android 5.0.x

Comment: Does it matter that I have android 5.1 (cm12.1) and I flashed gapps 5.0

Comment: Yes, it does matter. See the [CyanogenMod wiki on GApps](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps) to pick the matching GApps package.

Comment: OK. So I just copied over the gapps 5.1 to my device. So now I install from recovery

Comment: @KarimMaggio The instructions and troubleshooting are mentioned in the link *Izzy* commented. Click [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps#Installation) to see them.

Comment: You will have to reflash the rom and gapps package.